# How to combine two Schema.org types in Microdata?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

A few days ago, I was running a test on Google's structured data testing tool and suddenly, I ran a few more test for other sites where I found combined Schema.org types in `@jsonld`. As a Microdata lover, I wonder how is it possible to combine two different schema types (`Article` and `WebPage`) in HTML+Microdata?

Let's have a look on the regular markup example:

```
<div class='content-wrapper' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://schema.org/Article'>
  content goes here
</div>
```

To be more specific, I would like to combine `Article` and `WebPage` [like this](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=http%3A%2F%2Fsmallbusiness.chron.com%2Fproblems-facing-industrial-relations-4840.html). Is there any way to get the Microdata markup combined as shown in the example?

Answer (score 1):

In their case they have used a common @id (itemid in microdata) for two separate entities. That causes the entities to merge, and both types to be defined in the result.

The other way to do it is to enter them both into the itemtype, separated by a space:

```
<div class='content-wrapper' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://schema.org/Article http://schema.org/WebPage'>
  content goes here
</div>
```

Comment: Not working. Even the main microdata "article" gets disappear while following the snippets in your answer.

Comment: Oh God! It worked... thank you

Comment: Don't blame God 